# How to replace a value in a multiple level nesting in YAML using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Here is the YAML file:

```
test:
  title: ABC Company
  compId: '5161'
  accounts:
  - id: 1
    title: ABC Company
    MediaTypes:
    - title: AAA Company
      id: 66
      isSelected: true
```

I'm trying to write Ruby code to replace id: 1 (next level to accounts) to id: 2.

Here is my ruby code:

```
data = YAML::load(File.open(File.expand_path("../../../data/test.yml", __FILE__)))
data["test"]["accounts"]["id"] = 2
File.open((File.expand_path("../../../data/"test.yml", __FILE__)), 'w') {|f| f.write data.to_yaml }
```

When I run the script, the result is:

```
test:
  title: ABC Company
  compId: '5161'
  accounts: 2
```

Could someone please tell me what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
data["test"]["accounts"][0]["id"] = 2
```

Remember that accounts is an array of hashes, not a hash.

Comment: @chenlayton: Sure. Just remember that `-` indicates array element in YAML.